# Fourier Transform - Duality formula. What are the necessary conditions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I've come across two contradicting statements which I'd be glad if you could help me resolve:

***Theorem:*** if $f\left( x \right)$ is **continuous** and absolutely integrable ($\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\left| {f(x)} \right|dx}  < \infty $) and suppose $\widehat f\left( \omega  \right) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f\left( x \right){e^{ - i\omega x}}dx} $ is absolutely integrable ($\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ - \infty } {{{\left| {\widehat f\left( \omega  \right)} \right|}}d\omega }  < \infty $) then  $$F\left\{ {F\left\{ {f\left( x \right)} \right\}} \right\} = 2\pi f\left( { - x} \right)$$
Just to clarify notation: $F\left\{ {f\left( x \right)} \right\} = \widehat f\left( \omega  \right)$.

So this theorem assumes $f(x)$ is continuous on the real line.

But I really think we can demand less, that $f(x)$ be only piecewise continuous and get the continuity of $f(x)$ as a result of this theorem.

**My reasoning**:

if $f(x)$ is piecewise continuous and absolutely integrable then we know its fourier transform is continuous.

By the same thinking, since $F\left\{ {f\left( x \right)} \right\}$ is continuous and absolutely integrable then its fourier transform, $2\pi f\left( { - x} \right)$, is also continuous.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. But the Fourier inversion theorem for $f,\hat{f} \in L^1$ is what you need to prove the rest.

Comment: You mean that I first need to prove that if $f,\widehat f \in {L^1}$ then
$f\left( x \right) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\widehat f\left( \omega  \right){e^{i\omega x}}d\omega } $?
If so, should that equality hold pointwise or in the ${L^1}$ sense?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\widehat f\left( \omega  \right)e^{-\omega^2/n^2}e^{i\omega x}d\omega }$ converges to $2\pi f$ in quite all the normed space where $f$ belongs to. When $\widehat{f} \in L^1$ we can easily link it to $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int\limits_{ -n}^n  {\widehat f\left( \omega  \right)e^{i\omega x}d\omega }$ and obtain uniform convergence, $L^2$ convergence ...

Comment: What are the domains $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} ?$ and range $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} ?$ of your $f$ ?

Comment: A rather vague suggestion : you can pass from a piecewise linear function to a continuous fonction by convolving it with a continuous fonction. Thus I wouldn't be astonished that an explanation stems out of a certain convolution (known to be Fourier-friendly). But which one ? By the limit of a certain kernel ?

Comment: So you decided not to award the bounty?

Comment: I thought that If I accepted an answer (which I did) then the bounty was awarded. Was it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)= 0$ for $x\ne 0,$ $f(0)=1.$ Then $f$ is piecewise continuous on $\mathbb R.$ Since $f=0$ a.e., we have $F[f]\equiv 0,$ and hence $F[F[f]](x)\equiv 0.$ Thus $F[F[f]](x)$ does not equal $2\pi f(-x)$ everywhere.

If you view $f$ as an everywhere defined function, there's no way around this phenomenon. You can change $f$ on a set of measure $0$ but $F[f],$ and hence $F[F[f]],$ will not change.

But there is something you can say about Fourier inversion and piecewise continuous (PWC) functions. For simplicity suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ and $f\in L^1.$ I'm allowing any sort of discontinuity at $0$ at this point.

Claim: If $F[f]\in L^1,$ then $f$ has a removable singularity at $0.$

Proof: The well known inversion theorem for $L^1$ shows

$$f(x)= -\frac{F[F[f])(-x)}{2\pi}$$

for a.e. $x.$ Let $g$ be the function on the right; then $g$ is continuous everywhere. We then have $f=g$ a.e. everywhere on $(-\infty,0).$ But two continuous functions that agree a.e. on $(-\infty,0)$ actually agree everywhere on $(-\infty,0).$ (Nice exercise) The same holds on $(0,\infty).$ So we need only redefine $f(0)=g(0)$ and then $f= g$ everywhere. Thus $f$ has removable discontinuity at $0$ as claimed.

The claim extends to any finite number of discontinuities, with basically the same proof. It would also extend to a countable set of discontinuities if things are defined in the right way.